# Accessing Attribute in Controller Lightning Salesforce

Tags: lightning

I am trying to access the attribute which I am assigning the value in Helper, and calling the helper in Controller init, but while accessing the the same attribute in init, its returning undefined.

Here is my code

Helper

```
userName : function(component) {
    //loading user related data
    var action = component.get("c.getUserName");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.Name", response.getReturnValue());
           // alert('$$$' + component.get("v.Name"));

         }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);   
},
```

Controller

```
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {

    helper.userName(component);
    //here its returning undefined 
    alert(component.get("v.Name"));
}
```

Component

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}"/>

<aura:attribute name="Name" type="String" />
```

Comment: This is happening because of a well-known reason the `Asynchronous Ajax Request`.

Comment: The name will not get set until the callback occurs which is  after the code in unit has finished.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take help of callback to get the updated value after the `Ajax` call:

**Helper**

```
userName : function(component, callbackMathod) {
    //loading user related data
    var action = component.get("c.getUserName");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.Name", response.getReturnValue());
            alert('Called in helper: ' + component.get("v.Name"));
            if(callbackMathod){
                callbackMathod();
            }
         }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);   
},
```

**Controller**

```
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.userName(component, function(){
        alert('Called in controller: ' + component.get("v.Name"));
    }); 
}
```

**Component**

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}"/>

<aura:attribute name="Name" type="String" />
```

Comment: you are just awesome sir :)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment ,this is happening because in javascript the order of execution is not sequential like apex .

You generally do not need to access anything in your controller as the view is binded to the attribute and you can do further logic in the callback .

```
userName : function(component) {
//loading user related data
var action = component.get("c.getUserName");
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.Name", response.getReturnValue());
       //do your logic here .You can create functions or further callbacks or promises 

     }
  });
   $A.enqueueAction(action);   
 }
```

If you really want to understand the async behaviour.In the controller for some fun you can simply put a timeout function like below

```
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {

 helper.userName(component);
 window.setTimeout(
 $A.getCallback(function() {
    if (component.isValid()) {
        alert(component.get("v.Name"));
    }
 }),1000);
}
```

> Caution : Do not use this timeout method for any business logic .Its just for fun and help you understand how javascript is asynchronous in nature and even though the code block will be sequential the order of execution is not as place your code block .Here is an in depth articles to understand [callbacks](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/javascript-callbacks/)

Instead provide a callback implementation like below

```
({
    doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.userName(component,function(){
            alert(component.get("v.Name"));
        });
       }
   })

({
    userName : function(component,callback) {
    //loading user related data
    var action = component.get("c.getUserName");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.Name", response.getReturnValue());
           // alert('$$$' + component.get("v.Name"));
           if(callback){
                callback();
            }
         }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);   
}
})
```

Comment: There is a chance that @Abhi don't get the value in controller even after 1 second maybe because of the network speed and the processing time taken by `Apex`. So, even for the testing we should take help of  `callback method`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Completely agree .I have added a caution statement .Infact i would prefer all logic in the helper only .The reason why i have timeout is to demonstrate the async nature of javascript for an apex developer

Comment: the time out thing will be good for some time, but in my case I am having multiple helper functions, so for that call back method will be best, thanks for your help guys

Comment: Time out was to demonstrate the asynchronous behavior of JavaScript language and not to be used in the code .You should not chain multiple helper function in controller like that .it will be hard to maintain and debug and you will easily run into callback hell .A callback hell is common problem when you manage too many functions .An approach with ES6 promises will be elegant when you have so many functions .